# trying to run npm package (readability) from browser using Browserify with no success

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

so i'm trying to make readabilityJs available to me from the browser.

i want to use it later in my app, i'm using  BrowserifyJS + beefyJS to make it work.

here i'm trying to expose the function i want to use:

```
var read = require("readability-js");

module.exports = (url) => read(url, (err, article, meta) => {
  // Main Article
  console.log(article.content.text());
// 
  // Title
  console.log(article.title);

  // Article HTML Source Code
  console.log(article.content.html());
});
```

than i using the function in index.js

```
var readability = require("./Readability");

const url = "https://tim.blog/2019/10/31/edward-norton-motherless-brooklyn/";
readability(url);
```

after that i'm running browserify to make bundle.js and beefy to run it all

```
browserify index.js -o bundle.js
beefy index.js 8080
```

here is what i getting:

```
bundle.js:35798 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'content' of undefined
    at bundle.js:35798
    at bundle.js:62995
    at Request._callback (bundle.js:62933)
    at self.callback (bundle.js:63402)
    at emitOne (bundle.js:16927)
    at Request.emit (bundle.js:17005)
    at Request.self._buildRequest (bundle.js:63634)
    at Request.init (bundle.js:63812)
    at new Request (bundle.js:63378)
    at request (bundle.js:63059)
```

can you help me implement it right?